# How do I toggle CSS with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
$('#bc' + $.trim($this) + ' span.dashed-circle').css({ 'border' : '5px solid #000'});
```

That is triggered by a click.function().

I would like that to be a toggle - so when I click the element, it changes the border to what I have above...but when it is clicked again it disappears or rather sets the border to ' '.

Thoughts?

Edit: I should have been explicit...but I don't want to create a CSS class. The reason being is because when I do that, it messes up the formatting of the element being styled. I am sure that it is some small quirk somewhere that would fix it, but I am not interested in wading through the entire code base to fix little positioning issues with a new class. I would much rather just edit the css attribute directly - because it doesn't interfere with the layout.

Edit2: Here is the [jsfiddle of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/BMWZd/4/) I am trying to edit. If you notice, I have the CSS attributes last. But how do I let that be toggled ?

Edit3: If anyone is interested...the UI that this will be used in is for my webapp - http://www.compversions.com

Comment: look at jquery's toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: That was the first thing I did, but due to the way my code is it was giving me problems. Which is why I came here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("trigger-element").toggle( function() {
   $(element-to-change).css({ 'border' : '5px solid #000'});
   }, function () {
   $(element-to-change).css({ 'border' : 'none'});
});
```

Try This

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#panels tr table tr').toggle(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                tr_class = 'dash-elem-selected';
            if (!$this.parent('thead').length) {
                if ($this.hasClass(tr_class)) {
                    $this.removeClass(tr_class);
                    tr_class = 'removeClass';
                } else {
                    $this.addClass(tr_class).siblings().removeClass(tr_class);
                    tr_class = 'addClass';
                }
                $this = $this.parents('td table').siblings('.sit-in-the-corner').text();
                $('#bc' + $.trim($this) + ' span')[tr_class]('bc-dotted-to-solid');
                $('#bc' + $.trim($this) + ' span.dashed-circle').css({ 'border' : '5px solid #000'});
            }
        }, function() {
   //This is your new function that will turn off your border and do any other proccessing that you might need.
$('#bc' + $.trim($this) + ' span.dashed-circle').css({ 'border' : 'none'});
});
    });
```

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I want to do.

Comment: However, I am not quite sure how to apply it to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/BMWZd/4/  Thoughts?

Comment: I tried that and this is what I got...using your code exactly as you pasted it: http://jsfiddle.net/BMWZd/7/   The issue is, that once you click one of the elements in the box, it stays black when you are trying to remove it. So the other function in the toggle doesn't seem to be working (i.e. 'border' : 'none').

Answer (score 15):

I would do this by defining a `withborder` class and toggling that class.

CSS:

```
.withborder {
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#bc' + $.trim($this) + ' span.dashed-circle').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('withborder');
});
```

Comment: @lonesomeday.  i agree with your analysis except for one thing.  OP did not say that the click event was on `$('#bc' + $.trim($this) + ' span.dashed-circle')`

Comment: @John Hartsock I read "when I click the element" as referring to the element referred to in the selector.

Comment: @lonesomeday Your assumption may be correct but I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I was not specific enough. I don't want a new class. I have updated the question to add more specificity.

Comment: @marcamillion As you like, but there's no functional difference between doing this inline with `css` and with a class.

Comment: @lonesomeday I know the theory says that....but in practice, there is some funky layout I have going on - requiring specific positioning of other elements and stuff. So swapping classes creates mayhem - I guess that's the short answer.

Answer (score 12):

you could create a CSS class for this

```
.specialborderclass {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

Then in javascript toggle the class using [jQuery toggleClass() method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('.yourSelector').toggleClass("specialborderClass");
```

Comment: no `.` in the class name when you call  `toggleClass(".specialvorderClass")`

Comment: Thanks for this John, but I don't want another class. I want to simply edit the css. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I love this technique, especially because the code is concise and separates your CSS from JavaScript. Kudos!

Answer (score 4):

[Use toggle.](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

```
$("#IDOfElementYouClickOn").toggle(
      function(){$('#bc' + $.trim($this) + ' span.dashed-circle').css({ 'border' : '5px solid #000'});},
      function(){$('#bc' + $.trim($this) + ' span.dashed-circle').css({ 'border' : ''});}
    );
```

Comment: Adam, i like what you did here....but I am not quite sure how to apply to my code. See http://jsfiddle.net/BMWZd/4/  for what I am working with. I have also updated the question again.